# Audited - get instance of auditable object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-audited

I want to extend Audit record with some more information from the auditable type instance.

I've extended Audit behavior by `config/initializers/audited.rb`

```
class AuditExtension < Audited::Audit
  before_save :resolve_association

  def resolve_association
    puts auditable_id
    puts auditable_type
    x = auditable_type.constantize.find(auditable_id)
    ...
  end
end

Audited.config do |config|
  config.audit_class = AuditExtension
end
```

Is there any other way how can I get the instance of the class which is audited except the way of `x` initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `#auditable` on the `Audit` instance you have to access the object that was audited (e.g. `Audited::Audit.first.auditable`). Since this is a callback you should have access to it.